# About moving few methods to the superclass

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I need to move the same method from 4 different classes to the superclass.
Such methods are exactly the same except for the type of a variable declared in them:

For example, in the method in the first class I have

```
FirstClass var = [[FirstClass alloc] init]
```

in the second class

```
SecondClass var = [[SecondClass alloc] init]
```

and so on.

What's the best way to implement this variation in the superclass ?

Should I use NSClassFromString in the superclass and get each string from each method in the subclasses?

thanks

Comment: That's a way to do it.  There are probably a dozen variations.  But note that you can use `self` to obtain the class -- it will be the class of the subclass, not the superclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the different types of iVar's you intend on initializing in the subclasses are descended from a common class, then I'd store that class in the super, or else just store it as an id.  Then, setup a property accessor in each of your subclasses the casts the iVar as you need it.

```
@interface superClass : NSObject{
    id _superIvar;
}
@end

@implementation superClass : NSObject
    ....super's code....
@end
```

Now in the implementation of the subclass declare a property in a category, shown below (or in the interface, if you want it public)

```
@interface subClass (private)
@property (strong) ClassType *superIvar;
@end;

@implementation  
- (void) setSuperIvar:(ClassType *)superIvar{
    _superIvar = superIvar;
}
- (ClassType *) superIvar{
    return (ClassType *) _superIvar;
}

- (void) someMethodThatUsesSuperIvar{
    [self.superIvar doSomething];
}
@end
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to open your _superIvar to direct access, you can set a property on the superclass and access through the property on the subclass.  But in this way you can easily access super's ivars cast to the appropriate type.

Comment: Ok, so both answers suggest to use an iVar instead of declaring the var in the method as in my original code.

Comment: I think mine is subtly different than the other but either should work fine.  Subclasses can access the iVar of their super if it's not declared @private or declared in the implementation (.m file).  However, you can also setup a property accessor in the super and access it from the subclass via super.propery.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I get what you mean. So I could be answering the wrong question

If inside your class you need to use an object (I've called it worker below) to do your work, but the class of this object is not known til later, you can use dependency injection (DI).

**MyClass.h**

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) id<WorkerInterface> worker;

@end
```

**MyClass.m**

```
@implementation MyClass

@synthesize worker = _worker;

- (void)myMethod;
{
    [self.worker doSomething];
}

// You could also provide a default class to use if one is not passed in
//
// - (id<WorkerInterface)worker;
// {
//     if (!_worker) {
//         _worker = [[DefaultWorker alloc] init];
//     }
//     return _worker;
// }

@end
```

Now whenever I instantiate this class I can simply pass in the appropriate object to be used e.g:

```
MyWorkerClass *worker = [[MyWorkerClass alloc] init]; // <- Conforms to @protocol(WorkerInterface)
MyClass *instance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
instance.worker = worker;

[instance doSomething];
```

Comment: In short, (tell me if I'm wrong) instead of declaring the variable in the method, you use a property, initialized in the subclass.

Comment: The property is declared in the base class. You initialise and pass in the property whenever you create an instance of the base class or classes derived from it.